# Option lists in reStructuredText for command line arguments not prefixed with dashes or slashes

Tags: restructuredtext

reStructuredText has nice support for [option lists](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#option-lists). For example, [`rst2html.py`](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/user/tools.html#rst2html-py) translates this RST markup

```
Options:
    --foo                 does a foo
    -b, --bar ABAR        bar something
```

into the following nicely formatted HTML table:

```
<dt>Options:</dt>
<dd><table class="first last docutils option-list" frame="void" rules="none">
<col class="option" />
<col class="description" />
<tbody valign="top">
<tr><td class="option-group">
<kbd><span class="option">--foo</span></kbd></td>
<td>does a foo</td></tr>
<tr><td class="option-group">
<kbd><span class="option">-b</span>, <span class="option">--bar <var>ABAR</var></span></kbd></td>
<td>bar something</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</dd>
```

This doesn't seem to extend naturally to positional arguments, however; for example

```
Arguments:
    foo                   does a foo
    bar ABAR              bar something
```

renders as HTML completely lacking a table structure:

```
<dt>Arguments:</dt>
<dd>foo                   does a foo
bar ABAR              bar something</dd>
```

Is there some way to produce an options list table for command line arguments that are not prefixed by dashes or slashes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup. The rather limited syntax of option lists is not very well documented here:
http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#option-lists

Here's the really irritating thing. Say you are writing up a series of options and some of them fit the syntax of an "option" per the preceding link, but some do not. For example `--opt==keyword` does (and "keyword" will be italicized whether you want it or not), but `--pot=BLACK|KETTLE` doesn't. Docutils will put all the ones that fit their syntax into a nice option-list <table> template, but where they don't, it drops out of the table format and codes them as standard <dl>s. So right in the middle of your stack of options are a couple that don't look like the others.

Comment: Did you open a bug report?